# Returning the result changes the data in a javascript JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following code:

```js
function bestMove() {
  var url = "http://www.api.com"; // supposed to send {"location":4} in json format.
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  });
}

$(function() {

  console.log(bestMove())
  //driver code here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

the function `console.log(data);` in bestMove() logs `{location:4}`(which is what I want) but the one outside the function logs `undefined`. However, the variable data is returned so why would the values be different?

Also, when I use `JSON.parse(data)`, Chrome returns this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (tictactoe:5)
    at u (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to make the following updates to your code to achieve what you're after:

```
function bestMove() {
  var url = "http://www.api.com"; // supposed to send {"location":4} in json format.

  // Return the result of $.getJSON 
  return $.getJSON(url, function(data) { 
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  });
}

$(function() {

  // Add a then handler after bestMove() is called. The function
  // handler will give you access to driver data returned from to
  // ajax response
  bestMove().then(function(driver) {

    //driver code here
    console.log(driver)
  })
});
```

Comment: Sorry if the answer is kind of obvious but I still can't parse the data with `JSON.parse(driver)`. Thanks for the fast reply thou

Comment: @LuketheGeek `{location:4}` is a JavaScript object, not JSON. `$.getJSON` is already parsing the result for you. You're trying to parse something that's already been parsed :)

Comment: @TylerRoper But how can I get the value of `location` then?

Comment: @LuketheGeek It's an object, so you can do either `objectName.propertyName`, or `objectName["propertyName"]`. If your object is named `data` and the property you want is `location`, then you'd do `data.location`.

Comment: It's generally considered bad practice to simply give the code that solves someone's problem. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/6727154

Comment: @MichaelMontero This answer gives more than just code. An explanation is commented within the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the code like this

```
function bestMove(callback) {
 var url = "http://www.api.com"; // supposed to send {"location":4} in json format.
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

    return callback(null, data);
 });
}

$(function() {

 bestMove(function(err, data){
   console.log(data);
 });
});
```

Here I am using Error Callback first.
The data you get in callback function is Javascript Object which is already parsed and hence it is not necessary to parse the object. You can directly use it with "." operator or "[]" to access the property.

Comment: It's generally considered bad practice to simply give the code that solves someone's problem. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/6727154

Comment: Noted. Will consider hence forth.

Comment: Let me know the reason why it has been downvoted. Hence forth i will be aware of this.

Comment: I've downvoted your answer because you gave no explanation - it's code only, as has been pointed out. It's great that moving forward you'll be more aware, but if you'd like to have the downvote removed for *this* answer, then you should edit it to provide some more detail. (**EDIT:** You've provided a bit of detail so I'll now remove the downvote.)

Comment: Ohhk. I don`t have problem with downvote, I just want to know the reason. I will be aware of this. Thank you very much.